# Python: numpy.linalg.linalgerror: last 2 dimensions of the array must be square

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvalue

I have a matrix that gives out something like that:

```
a = 
[[ 3.14333470e-02  3.11644303e-02  3.03622814e-02  2.90406252e-02
   2.72220757e-02  2.49377488e-02  2.22267299e-02  1.91354055e-02
   1.57166688e-02  1.20290155e-02  8.13554227e-03  4.10286765e-03
  -8.19802426e-09 -4.10288390e-03 -8.13555810e-03 -1.20290306e-02
  -1.57166830e-02 -1.91354185e-02 -2.22267415e-02 -2.49377588e-02
  -2.72220839e-02 -2.90406315e-02 -3.03622856e-02 -3.11644324e-02
  -3.14333470e-02]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  2.90117128e-03  5.75270270e-03  8.50580375e-03
   1.11133681e-02  1.35307796e-02  1.57166756e-02  1.76336548e-02
   1.92489172e-02  2.05348252e-02  2.14693765e-02  2.20365808e-02
   2.22267328e-02  2.20365792e-02  2.14693735e-02  2.05348208e-02
   1.92489114e-02  1.76336477e-02  1.57166674e-02  1.35307704e-02
   1.11133581e-02  8.50579304e-03  5.75269150e-03  2.90115979e-03
  -1.15937571e-08]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  2.90117128e-03  5.75270270e-03  8.50580375e-03
   1.11133681e-02  1.35307796e-02  1.57166756e-02  1.76336548e-02
   1.92489172e-02  2.05348252e-02  2.14693765e-02  2.20365808e-02
   2.22267328e-02  2.20365792e-02  2.14693735e-02  2.05348208e-02
   1.92489114e-02  1.76336477e-02  1.57166674e-02  1.35307704e-02
   1.11133581e-02  8.50579304e-03  5.75269150e-03  2.90115979e-03
  -1.15937571e-08]]
```

and I want to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors

```
w, v = numpy.linalg.eig(a)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *directly* compute the eigenvalues of the matrix since it is not square. In order to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, the matrix has to be diagonalized, which involves taking a matrix inversion at an intermediate step, and [only square matrices are invertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix).

In order to find the eigenvalues from a non-square matrix you can compute the *singular value decomposition* (in numpy: [`np.linalg.svd`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html)). You can then relate the singular values with the eigenvalues as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320220/intuitively-what-is-the-difference-between-eigendecomposition-and-singular-valu), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583938/do-non-square-matrices-have-eigenvalues). Quoting one of the answers:

> Definition: The singular values of a `m×n` matrix A are the positive square roots of the nonzero eigenvalues of the corresponding matrix `A.T*A`. The corresponding eigenvectors are called the singular vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not square, just fill a zero column to fix it.

```
import numpy 

a = numpy.array(([1,7,3,9],[3,1,5,1],[4,2,6,3]))

# fill with zeros to get a square matrix
z = numpy.zeros((max(a.shape), max(a.shape)))
z[:a.shape[0],:a.shape[1]] = a
a = z
w, v = numpy.linalg.eig(a) 

print(w)

print(v)
```

Out:

```
[10.88979431 -2.23132083 -0.65847348  0.        ]
[[-0.55662903 -0.89297739 -0.8543584  -0.58834841]
 [-0.50308806  0.25253601 -0.0201359  -0.58834841]
 [-0.66111007  0.37258146  0.51929401  0.39223227]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.39223227]]
```